# Parsing string that looks like a list using ConfigArgParse

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.9.16 and `ConfigArgParse==1.7`.

I have conf file like this:

```ini
[conf] 
example = [something_in_brackets]
```

I am trying to parse the config like this:

```
import configargparse

p = configargparse.ArgParser(default_config_files=['conf.ini'])
p.add('--example')
conf = p.parse_args()

print(conf.example)
```

I want to read certain config value as string but sometimes the value will be in brackets making it look like a list.
When this happens `ConfigArgParse` gives following error:

```
parse.py: error: example can't be set to a list '['something_in_brackets']' unless its action type is changed to 'append' or nargs is set to '*', '+', or > 1
```

Quoting conf value in the ini file does not change behaviour.

Trying to use action type append or nargs values as suggested in the error message changes my config value to undesired form: `['something_in_brackets']` while it should be `[something_in_brackets]`.

I have also experimented with options of `p.add` such as `type=str` but I could not find a way to reach desired result.

Is it possible to parse config values like `[example]` with `ConfigArgParse` without having them turn into lists?

Comment: Have you tried quoting the value? `example = "[something_in_brackets]"`

Comment: (The relevant parsing code seems to be https://github.com/bw2/ConfigArgParse/blob/ee77f44d03415f2afe73c82096bae2293db29a3b/configargparse.py#L874-L882)

Comment: @AKX Yes, I tried quoting the value but behaviour with both double and single quotes is the same as it it without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The way is to get the value of example as string and then evaluate it as a list

```
import ast
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('conf.ini')

my_list = ast.literal_eval(config['conf']['example'])

# Print the list
print(my_list)
```

We use `ast.literal_eval` because it is more safer than `eval`

the config file

```
[conf]
example = [1, 2, 3]
```